# How to determine a and b where there is unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem below here with matrix:

ay + z=  0

ax + y=  1

2x + y − z = b

And i convert this to matrix form below here:

0  a 1 | 0

a  1 0 | 1

2  1 -1| b

And i have tried to solve this in a matrix calculator but i get some weird fractional form
and  i get stuck to on how to determine variable a and b should represent a unique solution?

Comment: Compute the determinant of the matrix on the left side. It is a quadratic polynomial in $a$. This has to be nonzero for a unique solution of $Ax=(0,1,b)^T$, which is given by $x=A^{-1}\cdot (0,1,b)^T$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burde is right. The hint is that you can check the necessary condition first. When the determinant of the coefficient matrix is $0$, you can get two values of a. (In order for you to check, a = 1 or -2.) Then, use gaussian elimination to determine which b(s) leads to contradiction.

Comment: okay i can decide a with help of that but how can i determine b i get x = b-1/2 ?

Comment: For example, when a=1, twice the second eq. minus the first get 2x+y-z=2, which means unique answer occurs iff b=2. The same with a=-2.

Comment: You mean inifinte solutions right?